# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, multer

In the front-end use form-data to send a post/put method to save data and edit data in the server. In the front-end have a problem with the image field. when new data is added. the new data will be saved. but when they try to edit data, the data changes made will not be saved, only saved if the image field is changed. (this problem only occurs in ios).
in IOS when they try to update data without changing the image field  server will be crashed

[image: error message]

```
router.put("/:id", authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  uploads(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return send(res, RESPONSE.FILE_TOO_LARGE);
    } else if (err) {
      return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
    }

    const params = {
      Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: `uploads/${uuid()}`,
      Body: req.file.buffer,
    };
    s3.upload(params, async (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
      }
      try {
        const id = req.params.id;
        const updatedData = {
          first_name: req.body.first_name,
          last_name: req.body.last_name,
          phone: req.body.phone,
          email: req.body.email,
          image: data.Key,
        };
        const options = { new: true };

      await SomeModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id.trim(), updatedData, options);
        return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS);
      } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should only do the S3 upload and set `image` if `req.file` is present

```js
router.put("/:id", authenticate, (req, res) => {
  uploads(req, res, async (err) => {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return send(res, RESPONSE.FILE_TOO_LARGE);
    } else if (err) {
      return send(res, RESPONSE.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
    }
    const id = req.params.id;
    const updatedData = {
      first_name: req.body.first_name,
      last_name: req.body.last_name,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      email: req.body.email,
    };

    try {
      if (req.file) {
        const { Key } = await s3
          .upload({
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key: `uploads/${uuid()}`,
            Body: req.file.buffer,
          })
          .promise();

        updatedData.image = Key;
      }
      await SomeModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id.trim(), updatedData, { new: true });
      return send(res, RESPONSE.SUCCESS);
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey Phil, the above code is working fine, kudos to you, and while updating the data (image storing in `diskStorage`) I have used the same method  ` if (req.file) { updateData.image = req.file.originalname; }` this is working for `multer.single()` method but there is null value is updating into DB while using `multer.array()` method, here is how i defined `if (req.files) {updateData.image = req.files.map((file) => file.originalname)}`, can you help me to fix this.